# TSD/DefinitelyTyped Install directory instead of specific file

Tags: cordova, typescript

I need to install an entire directory within the TSD repository instead of just a directory.

For example, running `tsd install cordova` only downloads the `cordova.d.ts` file within the `cordova` directory. I Also need the refences within `cordova.d.ts`, which are located within the `plugins` directory inside of the `cordova` directory.

So, I need something like `tsd install cordova/*`, which downloads all files/folders within the `cordova` directory.

Any thoughts on how this is possible?

EDIT:

I attempted to use the -r flag as the documentation states, but this is what I get:

```
>> tsd 0.5.7
-> warning path reference not in index: plugins/BatteryStatus.d.ts
-> warning path reference not in index: plugins/Camera.d.ts
-> warning path reference not in index: plugins/Contacts.d.ts
-> warning path reference not in index: plugins/Device.d.ts
-> warning path reference not in index: plugins/DeviceMotion.d.ts
-> warning path reference not in index: plugins/DeviceOrientation.d.ts
-> warning path reference not in index: plugins/Dialogs.d.ts
-> warning path reference not in index: plugins/FileSystem.d.ts
-> warning path reference not in index: plugins/FileTransfer.d.ts
-> warning path reference not in index: plugins/Globalization.d.ts
-> warning path reference not in index: plugins/InAppBrowser.d.ts
-> warning path reference not in index: plugins/Media.d.ts
-> warning path reference not in index: plugins/MediaCapture.d.ts
-> warning path reference not in index: plugins/NetworkInformation.d.ts
-> warning path reference not in index: plugins/Push.d.ts
-> warning path reference not in index: plugins/Splashscreen.d.ts
-> warning path reference not in index: plugins/Vibration.d.ts
-> warning path reference not in index: plugins/WebSQL.d.ts

 - cordova/cordova.d.ts : <head> : 2014-08-21 12:11

>> running install..
    > skipped existing: cordova/cordova.d.ts

>> written zero files
```

It still only installs the main `cordova/cordova.d.ts` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have run into this issue with cordova, and the only way I found to fix it was to use grunt. I typically have a "grunt install" task to run tsd, bower, etc.

You can use [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) and [grunt-contrib-clean](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-clean) to do this.

Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/wjohnsto/882ee6dd3b277d08059c). You will probably have to modify it to suit your needs, but it's a start. It's not the most elegant solution, but it is far better than installing the cordova dependencies manually.

Answer (score 4):

TSD author here: This is a known issue on 0.5.x, but it is solved in 0.6.0: I'm releasing it to npm any day now, or see this ticket on how to get the prerelease: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd/issues/100

Then in 0.6 you can do:

```
tsd install cordova/ -rs
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `resolve` flag i.e. `-r` e.g.

```
tsd query cordova -a install -r
```

Comment: I tried that previously, should have mentioned that. See my edit for info.